# Is it possible to save/restore just window layout (no buffers etc.)?

Tags: window-management, layout

Currently I'm using Vim sessions to restore my window layout, but this approach also restores buffers, which I'd prefer to be closed on startup.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
$ vim file.txt
```

And in Vim something like:

```
: restore-layout
```

The only variant I can think of is to create a function which will do this, but it's not convenient for me.

---

Though it just occurred to me, that it may be convenient to **define a function, which will wipe out all buffers** with some exceptions. I may call this function automatically during a session restoration.

I'll try this later today.

Thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've ended with this piece in my vimrc:

```
fun! BuffWipe()
  for nr in range(1, bufnr('$'))
    if (bufwinnr(nr) == -1) && (bufexists(nr))
      exec 'bw ' . nr
    endif
  endfor
endfun
```

Which I call before creating a session on `VimLeave`.

*For some reason it doesn't wipe out all buffers I'd expect (which are those, that are not being visible in any window), but it wipes almost all of them*.

I find this approach to be rather convenient, since it allows me to close numerous buffers I finished working with all at once.

Comment: Remove `buffers` from `ssop`

Comment: @Matt I did, and `vim -S my-session-script.vim` still restored all the buffers, which had been open when I exited vim. So I don't think that simply removing 'buffers' could help

Answer (score 1):

A window cannot exist without any buffer attached.

Just make sure you have an empty unnamed buffer in every window and save the session.